# Mongodb distinct on a key in a key value pair situation

Tags: mongodb

I have the bellow document structure in mongodb, I want to bring **distinct** keys from the column `customData`
So if you look bellow, I want my result to be: `key1,key2,key3,key4`

doing

```
db.coll.distinct("customData")
```

will bring the values and not the keys.

```
{
   "_id":ObjectId("56c4da4f681ec51d32a4053d"),
   "accountUnique":7356464,
   "customData":{
      "key1":1,
      "key2":2,
   }
}

{
   "_id":ObjectId("56c4da4f681ec51d32a4054d"),
   "accountUnique":7356464,
   "customData":{
      "key3":1,
      "key4":2,
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible to do this with **[Map-Reduce](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce/)** since you have dynamic subdocument keys which the distinct method will not return a result for.

Running the following mapreduce operation will populate a separate collection with all the keys as the `_id` values:

```
var myMapReduce = db.runCommand({
    "mapreduce": "coll",
    "map" : function() {
        for (var key in this.customData) { emit(key, null); }
    },
    "reduce" : function() {}, 
    "out": "coll_keys"
})
```

To get a list of all the dynamic keys, run distinct on the resulting collection:

```
db[myMapReduce.result].distinct("_id")
```

will give you the sample output

```
["key1", "key2", "key3", "key4"]
```